# webgl multiple fragment shaders on a image using frame buffer object gives black output

Tags: javascript, webgl, textures, framebuffer

First off, I'm new at WebGL. I am trying to applying multiple fragment shaders(here, 2 shaders) on a single image to be rendered. I read in different articles and other stack overflow questions that we should use framebuffers (ping pong method) for this purpose but couldn't find any sample code snippets anywhere.  What I understood is first I create two programs each with a different fragment shader. Then use a framebuffer object where I can use my first program (first shader) on the original image and output it to that fbo texture. Then use this output texture as the input in the second program so that both shaders are retained. This output is finally rendered on the canvas.
I tried doing the same thing , but my canvas is completely black. I am not getting any errors in the console everything seems fine but not result.
I am struck with for hours . Could anyone help me check it?
Below is the code I wrote

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
//create two programs using a createprogram function written in my code.
const programA = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShaderA); // program using #shader1
const programB = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShaderB);
const texFbPair = createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl); //function defined below
setAttributes(programA);
setAttributes(programB);

function setAttributes(program) {
    const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
    const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1,
        1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1,
    ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    const texCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");
    const texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
}

const texture = gl.createTexture();
texture.image = new Image();
texture.image.onload = function () {
    handleLoadedTexture(gl, texture);
};
texture.image.crossOrigin = '';
texture.image.src = 'skogafoss_waterfall_iceland.jpg';
function handleLoadedTexture(gl, texture, callback) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
}

gl.useProgram(programA);
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, texFbPair.fb);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

gl.useProgram(programB);
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texFbPair.tex);
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6)

function createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl) {
    const tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
    return { tex: tex, fb: fb };
}
```

Comment: FYI: There's [an example](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html), [here's another](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing-continued.html)

Comment: I pasted the code wrong initially it has `gl.texImage2D` function call in `createTextureAndFramebuffer` function, which I edited and included now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like from your code you have a mis-understanding of how attributes work. Attributes are global state in WebGL1 so these lines

```
setAttributes(programA);
setAttributes(programB);
```

Won't work. The second call to `setAttributes` will just change the global attributes to the second call's settings.

See [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-attributes.html) and [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html)

The next issue is the code does not wait for the image to load so it creates an image, sets a callback for when it finishes loading, it then draws 2 things. Then later, the image finishes loading and is copied to the texture but no drawing happens after that.

The code also never allocates the actual texture in `createTextureAndFramebuffer`

To do that you to call `gl.texImage2D`

Here is some working code.

```js
const vertexShader = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
`;

const fragmentShaderA = `
precision highp float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, v_texCoord);
}
`;

const fragmentShaderB = `
precision highp float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, v_texCoord);
}
`;

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
//create two programs using a createprogram function written in my code.
const programA = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShaderA); // program using #shader1
const programB = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShaderB);
const texFbPair = createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl); //function defined below

function setAttributes(program) {
    const positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
    const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1,
        1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1,
    ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    const texCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_texCoord");
    const texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
}

const texture = gl.createTexture();
texture.image = new Image();
texture.image.onload = function () {
    handleLoadedTexture(gl, texture);
};
texture.image.crossOrigin = '';
texture.image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/ZKMnXce.png';
function handleLoadedTexture(gl, texture, callback) {
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
    

    setAttributes(programA);
    gl.useProgram(programA);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, texFbPair.fb);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    setAttributes(programB);
    gl.useProgram(programB);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texFbPair.tex);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6)}


function createTextureAndFramebuffer(gl) {
    const tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(
       gl.TEXTURE_2D,
       0, // mip level
       gl.RGBA, // internal format
       gl.canvas.width, // width
       gl.canvas.height, // height
       0, // border
       gl.RGBA, // format
       gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
       null); // data
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    const fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D( gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
    return { tex: tex, fb: fb };
}

function createProgram(gl, vs, fs) {
  return twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Other things I noticed.

The uniforms for the samplers are never looked up (of course I don't know what your actual shaders look like, I used placeholders). As such it works because uniforms default to 0 so the programs will reference the texture bound to texture unit 0 which is the default.

I also noticed the first draw via the framebuffer sets the viewport to the size of the canvas. That's correct if the size of the attachments in the framebuffer are the size of the canvas (which I made them be when I added the call to `texImage2D`) but it would probably be more appropriate to record a width and height for that texture so if you change its size the code won't fail.

Finally while I moved the calls to `setAttributes` to the correct places it's not common to also create and fill out buffers when rendering. It's more common to create buffers at init time and set attributes at render time but I didn't want to change more code.

You might find [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org) helpful.

Comment: Thank you @gman, I was doing it wrong at `setAttribute`. Changed it and its working well now. Also,my shaders have only one sampler so I never looked up for them as default texture 0 will be bound I guess that wont be an issue